# ¿Cómo vamos a pretender que un usuario nuevo lea la ayuda si quedó escondida en la nueva barra?

Tags: soporte, usuarios-nuevos, barra-superior, centro-de-ayuda

La nueva barra superior trajo un mejor diseño, mucho más minimalista , pero la ayuda pasó a estar algo escondida:

[image: Menú SE - ayuda]

¿Esto no va a traer problemas con los nuevos usuarios? Ya demasiado poco la leen, ¿no nos perjudicaría?

Comment: El problema descrito **ya no puede reproducirse**. Las modificaciones en el sistema, o en las circunstancias que lo afectan, lo han vuelto obsoleto. Si encuentras un problema similar, por favor [formula una nueva pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### ¡La ayuda está ahí para los usuarios de menor reputación!

[image: Menú "?" despliega: Recorrido, Centro de ayuda, Meta, Sobre nosotros, Negocios]

- Disponible para usuarios con menos de [500](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) de reputación (sin acceso a revisión).

---

**¿Y para los usuarios con 500+ que encuentran incómoda la ubicación de la ayuda?**

Habiliten **[atajos de teclado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/mine)** y presionen <kbd>G</kbd> → <kbd>E</kbd>.

<sup>* Más información en [¿Qué combinaciones de teclas hay disponibles en el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2178/127)</sup>

Comment: ¿De dónde sacaste lo de que está disponible para usuarios con menos de 500 de reputación? También me suena, pero no encuentro la referencia. Lo consulto en relación a [una pregunta en Meta.Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2723/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui lo busco y te aviso si lo encuentro... Era en alguna publicación de MSO... Es 500 porque es cuando se accede a revisión, y podés verlo abriendo una ventana de incógnito en la que no hayas iniciado sesión.

Comment: @fedorqui https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone/343184#comment444046_343165

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Sí, hice la prueba usando ventana de incógnito, así como mirando en distintos sitios Beta donde estoy registrado y en los que tengo reputación mayor o menos de 350.