# ¿Qué combinaciones de teclas hay disponibles en el sitio?

Tags: soporte, faq, formato

Soy usuario de UNIX de toda la vida y utilizar el ratón me parece una pérdida de tiempo si con el teclado ya puedo hacer lo que quiero. Por ello, estoy muy agradecido a Stack Exchange por ofrecer combinaciones de teclas para algunas tareas regulares del sitio.

Dado que voy descubriendo combinaciones de vez en cuando, intuyo que habrá muchas y algunas no las conozco. ¿Cuáles son todas ellas?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Durante una edición

He aquí las combinaciones disponibles a la hora de editar publicaciones, especificadas en la [Ayuda de markdown](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> → Negritas
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> → Insertar imagen
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> → Encabezados
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> → Cursivas
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> → Ejemplo de código
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> → Enlace
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> → Lista ordenada
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> → Cita en bloque
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> → Regla horizontal
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> → Lista con viñetas

---

### Atajos del teclado

Se deben activar, dentro de tu perfil, en la [configuración de preferencias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/mine). Se activan independientemente por sitio, y es necesario realizarlo para cada uno de los sitios en los que participes (o utilizar un script).

He aquí las combinaciones disponibles a través del centro de ayuda (que también se visualizan sobre la página al presionar <kbd>?</kbd>):

#### Globales

- <kbd>G</kbd> → Ir a...

  - <kbd>H</kbd> → [página de inicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
  - <kbd>Q</kbd> → [preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions)
  - <kbd>T</kbd> → [etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags)
  - <kbd>U</kbd> → [usuarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users)
  - <kbd>B</kbd> → [medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)
  - <kbd>N</kbd> → [sin responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)
  - <kbd>M</kbd> → [sitio Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/)
  - <kbd>C</kbd> → [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com)
  - <kbd>E</kbd> → [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)
  - <kbd>F</kbd> → [preguntas frecuentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (recorrido)
- <kbd>R</kbd> → logros recientes
- <kbd>S</kbd> → buscar
- <kbd>?</kbd> → ayuda
- <kbd>H</kbd> → desactivar auto ayuda

#### Perfil

- <kbd>I</kbd> → navegación en-página...

  - <kbd>T</kbd> → tab

    - <kbd>P</kbd> → perfil
    - <kbd>A</kbd> → actividad
    - <kbd>E</kbd> → edición de perfil y configuración
  - <kbd>U</kbd> → usuario

    - ...

#### Publicaciones / Usuarios / Etiquetas

- <kbd>U</kbd> → seleccionar primer publicación / usuario / etiqueta
- <kbd>J</kbd> → seleccionar siguiente publicación / usuario/ etiqueta
- <kbd>K</kbd> → seleccionar publicación / usuario /etiqueta anterior
- <kbd>P</kbd> → página...

  - <kbd>P</kbd> → página anterior
  - <kbd>N</kbd> → siguiente página
  - <kbd>L</kbd> → última página
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> → Ingresar

#### Publicaciones

- <kbd>V</kbd> → votar...

  - <kbd>U</kbd> → a favor
  - <kbd>D</kbd> → en contra
- <kbd>A</kbd> → respuesta
- <kbd>E</kbd> → editar
- <kbd>T</kbd> → reetiqueta
- <kbd>C</kbd> → añadir/mostrar comentarios
- <kbd>L</kbd> → enlace
- <kbd>M</kbd> → moderar...

  - <kbd>F</kbd> → reportar
  - <kbd>C</kbd> → cerrar
- <kbd>O</kbd> → ordenar respuestas por...

  - <kbd>A</kbd> → actividad
  - <kbd>O</kbd> → más antiguas
  - <kbd>V</kbd> → votos

... muchos más por añadir, se reproducen rápidamente...

Comment: Publicación en proceso de completado. Descubrí que 1) hay muchas y 2) no están listadas en ningún sitio, luego toca ir descubriendo los atajos de ayuda a base de ir a todas las posibles páginas. Gracias @Mariano por mejorarlo tan sustancialmente.

Comment: Las uso todo el tiempo, me las sé de memoria. De todas formas, sólo copié el texto del modal que aparece con los atajos ;-)

Comment: Buenisima aportación. Muchas gracias ^^ (aunque yo uso cVim pra moverme por las paginas)